# How do I prevalue a field based on the choice of another field in react

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to prepopulate the 'rata' field based on the selection of the 'categories' field. When a user chooses the category of the file, I would like to prepopulate the 'rata' field with a default value, while still allowing the user to change it. It should only serve as a default value.

```
return (
<div>
  {
    uploadAlert.message &&
    <AlertBox
      action={uploadAlert.action}
      message={uploadAlert.message}
      handleAlertClose={handleAlertClose}
    />
  }
  <h2>File Uploader</h2>

  <div className={styles.drop_area}>

    <Dropzone accept="application/pdf" onDrop={handleDrop}>
      {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
        <div {...getRootProps()} className={styles.drop_zone_text}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Drag and drop a PDF file here, or click to select a file</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </Dropzone>
  </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div className={styles.input_error}>
    {fileError}
  </div>
  <div className={styles.fileList}>
    {
      selectedFiles.map((file, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>

            <div className={styles.file_select_container}>

              <div className={styles.left_content}>
              {/* <div > {file.file.name}</div> */}
              <div className={styles.left_content_grid}>
                <Grid container spacing={2} style={{ width: '100%'  }}>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={1.8} >
                  <div style={{ wordBreak: 'break-all' }} > {file.file.name}</div>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={2.5} >
                    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: '100%' }} size='small'>
                      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label">Tipo polizza</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
                        value={file.category}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          console.log(e.target.value)
                          handleInput('category',e.target.value, index)
                        }}
                        width="100%"
                        label="category"
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="">
                          <em>None</em>
                        </MenuItem>
                        {
                          categories.map((item, index) => {
                            return <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
                          })
                        }
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>  
                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={1.5}>
                    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: '100%' }} size='small'>
                      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label">Compagnia</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-autowidth-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select-autowidth"
                        value={file.subCategory}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          console.log(e.target.value)
                          handleInput('subCategory',e.target.value, index)
                        }}
                        width="100%"
                        label="subMenu"
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="">
                          <em>None</em>
                        </MenuItem>
                        {console.log(file.category)}
                        {
                          file.category && subMenu[file.category].map((item, index) => {
                            return <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>{item.name}</MenuItem>
                          })
                        }
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>

                  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={1.7}>
                    <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: '100%' }} size="small">
                      <InputLabel id="etichetta-scelta-multipla">Rata</InputLabel>
                      <Select
                        labelId="etichetta-scelta-multipla"
                        id="campo-scelta-multipla"
                        value={selectedFiles[index].rata}
                        onChange={(e) =>handleInput('rata', '', index, e.target.value)}
                        width="100%"
                        label="rata"
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="">
                          <em>Nessuna</em>
                        </MenuItem>
                        {opzioniSceltaMultipla.map((opzione) => (
                          <MenuItem key={opzione.value} value={opzione.value}>
                            {opzione.label}
                          </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Grid>

                  {/* Nuovo campo*/}
                </Grid>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div className={`${styles.right_content} ${styles.content_pointer}`}>
                <CloseIcon onClick={() => removeFileByIndex(index)} fontSize='medium' />
            </div>
              </div>
                {file.error && <div className={styles.input_error} style={{ marginLeft: "20px", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
                {file.error}
              </div>}
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
  
  <Flex direction="row-reverse" style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
    <Button onClick={handleUpload} isLoading={loading}>Upload files</Button>
    <Button onClick={removeAll} color="blue.60" border="none">Clear All</Button>
  </Flex>

</div>
 );
  };

 export default FileUploadeCompont;
```

how can i do it? thanks for the help

Comment: I think you would use useState and set the initial value to what you want and then set the control value to be controlled by the state and the the change event can update the state.

Comment: `defaultValue` only plays when initially rendering the component. Changing it does nothing afterward. The best bet is to store the value of your field that you want to change in a state and define its current value from the state. That way you can modify its form from any other field and update the wanted field value on a go. State> state value into your field. another field > on change > set state value.